# How to arrive at irq base for an mfd device?

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

In an `MFD` device. I wanted to understand, how do we arrive at `irq base`. Is it a random number.?

Please some one explain.

Comment: What `irq base` are you referring to? Links/code please...

Comment: Consider a driver max77693. It is an mfd device. It has multiple interrupts. so in that driver, they have chosen one irq_base number randomly and have mapped(not exact mapping, direct assignment starting with enum 0+irq_base).
Reference:'http://lxr.linux.no/linux+v3.10.7/drivers/mfd/max77693-irq.c#L243.'
Note: we have ported this driver to device tree style.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically one first needs to associate a particular IRQ number with an actual physical hardware interrupt before attempting to register an ISR for that IRQ number. This is commonly done in the Linux kernel using [**`irq_domain_add_linear()`**](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/kernel/irq/irqdomain.c?v=3.5#L217).

> In the past, IRQ numbers could be chosen so they matched the hardware IRQ line into the root interrupt controller (i.e. the component actually firing the interrupt line to the CPU) **nowadays this number is just a number**.
>
> The **`irq_alloc_desc*()`** and **`irq_free_desc*()`** APIs provide allocation of irq numbers, but they don't provide any support for reverse mapping of the controller-local IRQ (hwirq) number into the Linux IRQ number space.
>
> The current design of the Linux kernel uses a single large number space where each separate IRQ source is assigned a different number. This is simple when there is only one interrupt controller, but in systems with multiple interrupt controllers the kernel must ensure that each one gets assigned non-overlapping allocations of Linux IRQ numbers.

More details in the Linux-kernel **[Documentation/IRQ-domain.txt](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/IRQ-domain.txt)**.

Comment: I had been through this document and given a thought of doing so.. was hesitant about giving a try. got a kick start.. will do.. thanks. +1