# how interrupt id and ISR is mapped?

Tags: linux-kernel, operating-system, linux-device-driver, kernel-module

I am studying the lab 4 from CS.USFCA which generates a simulated interrupt to the virtual NIC. 
class page:
http://cs.usfca.edu/~cruse/cs686s08/

The program will create a emulated NIC interface and user can manually issue a interrupt to the NIC by cat the proc.

**Steps:**

1. **cat /proc/interrupt** to select a proper IRQ, and I select IRQ #18
2. then I print the content of IOAPIC. the entry#18 bit0-7 is 55, so I set IntID as 55.
3. Next, I install the module, and use **ifconfig** to bring up eth3. The IRQ is 18 which is correct.
4. while tring to simulate the interrupt by **cat /proc/netframe**, the kernel log shows that
   **[18828.842375] do_IRQ: 1.85 No irq handler for vector (irq -1)**

I know Linux manage 0-255 interrupt vectors by itself, and the 24 entries in IOAPIC decides how Interrupt from IO device is delivered to CPU(Intel).
in my case, it seems I triggers a wrong interrupt. So CPU cannot find the correct irq handler.

**But how the interrupt is mapped to the corresponding IRQ in my case?**

[image]

[image]

[image]

my code

```
#include <linux/module.h>   // for init_module() 
#include <linux/etherdevice.h>  // for alloc_etherdev()
#include <linux/proc_fs.h>  // for create_proc_info_entry() 
#include <linux/interrupt.h>    // for request_irq(), free_irq()
#include <linux/wait.h>     // for init_wait_queue_head()
#include <linux/seq_file.h>

#define irqID       0x12    // temporary -- an unused IRQ
#define intID       0x55    // temporary -- IOAPIC mapped  

typedef struct  {
    struct tasklet_struct   my_rxtasklet;
    wait_queue_head_t   my_waitqueue;
    spinlock_t      my_lock;
} MY_DRIVERDATA;


int my_open( struct net_device * );
int my_stop( struct net_device * );
int my_hard_start_xmit( struct sk_buff *, struct net_device * );
irqreturn_t my_isr( int, void * );
void my_rx_handler( unsigned long );
int my_get_info( char *, char **, off_t, int );

char modname[] = "netframe";

static const struct net_device_ops mynetdev_ops={
    .ndo_open=my_open,
    .ndo_stop       = my_stop,
    .ndo_start_xmit = my_hard_start_xmit,
}; 

struct net_device  *netdev;

int my_get_info( char *buf, char **start, off_t off, int count )
{
    int len = 0;
    int i;
    *start = buf;
    if ( off == 0 )
    {
        len += sprintf( buf+len, "simulating an interrupt " );
        len += sprintf( buf+len, "by \'%s\' \n", netdev->name  );
        off += len;
    } 
    else
    {
        asm(" int %0 " : : "i" (intID) );
    }

    return  len;
}  

static int my_seq_open(struct inode *inode,struct file *file){
    printk(KERN_ALERT "DEBUG: Enter %s\n",__FUNCTION__);
    return single_open(file, &seq_proc_show,NULL);
}

struct file_operations fops = {
    .read=my_get_info,
};

static int __init my_init( void )
{ 
    printk( "<1>\nInstalling \'%s\' module\n", modname );

    if(!proc_create(modname,0666,NULL,&fops)){
        printk(KERN_INFO "ERROR! proc_create\n");
        remove_proc_entry(modname,NULL);
        return -1;
    }
    netdev = alloc_etherdev( sizeof( MY_DRIVERDATA ) );
    if ( !netdev ) return -ENOMEM;
    netdev->irq     = irqID;
    netdev->netdev_ops=&mynetdev_ops;

    return  register_netdev( netdev );  
} 

static void __exit my_exit(void )
{
    unregister_netdev( netdev );
    free_netdev( netdev );
    remove_proc_entry( modname, NULL );
    printk( "<1>Removing \'%s\' module\n", modname );
}

int my_open( struct net_device *dev ) 
{  
    MY_DRIVERDATA   *priv = netdev_priv(dev);
    unsigned long   devaddr = (unsigned long)dev;

    printk( "opening the \'%s\' interface \n", dev->name );

    spin_lock_init( &priv->my_lock );
    init_waitqueue_head( &priv->my_waitqueue );
    tasklet_init( &priv->my_rxtasklet, my_rx_handler, devaddr );

    if ( request_irq( dev->irq, my_isr, IRQF_SHARED, dev->name, dev ) < 0) return -EBUSY;

    netif_start_queue( dev );
    return 0; 
}

int my_stop( struct net_device *dev ) 
{ 
    MY_DRIVERDATA   *priv = netdev_priv(dev);

    printk( "stopping the \'%s\' interface \n", dev->name );

    free_irq( dev->irq, dev );

    tasklet_kill( &priv->my_rxtasklet );
    netif_stop_queue( dev );
    return 0; 
}

int my_hard_start_xmit( struct sk_buff *skb, struct net_device *dev )
{ 
    MY_DRIVERDATA   *priv = netdev_priv(dev);

    printk( "starting transmit on the \'%s\' interface \n", dev->name );

    dev->trans_start = jiffies;
    dev->stats.tx_packets += 1;
    dev->stats.tx_bytes += skb->len;

    wait_event_interruptible( priv->my_waitqueue, 1 );

    dev_kfree_skb( skb );
    return 0;
}

irqreturn_t my_isr( int irq, void *data )
{ 
    struct net_device   *dev = (struct net_device*)data;
    MY_DRIVERDATA   *priv = netdev_priv(dev);
    tasklet_schedule( &priv->my_rxtasklet );
    wake_up_interruptible( &priv->my_waitqueue );
    return  IRQ_HANDLED;
} 

void my_rx_handler( unsigned long data )
{
    struct net_device   *dev = (struct net_device *)data;
    struct sk_buff      *skb;
    int         rxbytes = 60;

    skb = dev_alloc_skb( rxbytes + 2 );
    skb->dev = dev;
    skb->protocol = eth_type_trans( skb, dev );
    skb->ip_summed = CHECKSUM_NONE;
    dev->stats.rx_packets += 1;
    dev->stats.rx_bytes += rxbytes;
    netif_rx( skb );
} 

module_init( my_init );
module_exit( my_exit );
MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");
```

Comment: How interrupts are assigned and shared, and how they bubble up from hardware through the system is a huge subject, and this question doesn't really match SO very well. You're probably best off meeting with your professor during office hours - they'll be able to explain things at an appropriate level and focus on the parts that are relevant to your class.

Comment: @katie I am not a student, but just do it for self-learning.  just hope someone can give me a hit or something. That would be much appreciated. :)

Comment: 1. Too many questions in one post. 2. Code should be included into question post, not linked. See [How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: What is your kernel version ? 2.6.22.5 ?

Comment: @Maquefel kernel is 3.13.0-37-generic

Comment: @Tsyvarev I further edit my question. I just dont understand how to trigger the IRQ handler by a proper interrupt ID.

Comment: @Craig are you using some kind of emulator or experimenting  on your own PC?

Comment: @Maquefel Yes, the OS is running on VMware workstation. Do you mean running the OS on a physical machine instead on a virtual one, then I can get the expected result by this procedure?

Comment: No - it is not so easy.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101697/discussion-between-maquefel-and-craig).

Comment: @Craig Not a direct answer to your question, but does **[this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18280261/319204)** help?...